# Changing gears at what speed?

Tags: gears, torque

Can someone please link me to a website where I can get the speed at which a car must shift gears, (manufacturer wise would be better).
Or maybe, link to a website where I will be able to calculate the recommended speed to shift gears. Known is the gear ratios, max power@rpm, max torque@rpm, wheel diameter. Now how do I calculate the recommended speed to shift all gears.
Lets take Hyundai i10 or Maruti Alto 800 for example.

Comment: [This article](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-calculate-the-best-RPM-for-shifting-gears-to-get-the-highest-acceleration) has an interesting take on how to choose the RPM to shift at. Once you have the RPM, you can just multiply through by final drive ratio, gear ratio, and wheel circumference to find vehicle speed to shift at

Comment: each engine has it's own RPM limit.  Each transmission has it's own gear ratios.  There's essentially no answer to your question.  In BMW S1000RR the end of first gear is 92mph.  On a Honda CM200 it's about 25mph just to give you an idea.  I know your not dealing with MC's but it's the same thing with cars.

Comment: Try [this calculator](http://glennmessersmith.com/shiftpt.html#data). You will need to know the trend of torque vs. RPM (which you can get by google-ing your car type and "dyno" -- e.g. "Hyundai i10 dyno", view images, then pick points off the graph and enter them into the relevant fields)

Comment: @costrom http://www.andysautosport.com/learning_center/calculators/ was there in the Quora answer that you linked. So, the calculator is awesome! Can you please help me with the steps how did they arrived at the recommended speed at which gear should be changed vs rpm

Comment: What if your users has a 2015 Camaro or Porsche or even a mid pack Lexus sedan?

Comment: You should come to chat.  @SoumyaSen   you may get better help there. Pulling random vehicles out of the hat has little benefit....but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Judging from question history your developing an app, if so I would suspect you would want universal coverage for your user base.

Comment: Here's a chat link.    http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop

Comment: Soumya, the calculators on that page are not really relevant to **when** to change gear. The article costrom posted does tell you.

Comment: There is too much variance amongst models.  You need a feed of gear ratios, tire diameters, final drive ratio as well as redline to design an algorithm for this to be beneficial.  I'll bet writing this app is a lot bigger than you thought when you said you would do it.   :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think I got this.  someone help me verify...

So I watch the tach and speedo to determine MPH per 1000 RPM in higher gears (3rd,4th,5th).  On my car its about 10, 15, 19.5.

[tire diameter (in inches)] * [pi] * [1/(gear ratio * final drive ratio)] / [in/ft] / [ft/mi] * [RPM] * [min/hr] = MPH

constants
pi = 3.14159
in/ft = 12
ft/mi = 5280
min/hr = 60

calculated
I used my car in 4th gear since I know the tire size, approx gear ratio, FD and what the answer should be.
tire diameter - used an online calculator - 195/55R15 = 23.4in
gear ratio - 1.00 (I think this is off slightly, but close enough)
FD ratio - 4.40
RPM - 1000

23.4 * 3.14 * ( 1 / ( 1.00 * 4.40 ) ) / 12 / 5280 * 1000 * 60 = 15.81

This seems to be about correct.  My internet is being funky so I can't look up my exact ratios right now.

There are a couple things that will throw this off such as tire diameter not being exactly as advertised, tach and speedo not being 100% accurate.  Doing this as one equation and using a calculators pi gives more accurate results due to significant digits.

Now if you want to determine where to shift, plug in the RPM of the redline for that vehicle.  All of the calculated values need to be calculated specifically for the vehicle in question.

**EDIT**

3rd - 1.360 = 11.6
4th - 1.034 = 15.3
5th - 0.787 = 20.1

These are close, a little high.  This is expected since tires on the ground aren't exactly round (contact patch on the ground) and accounting for wear.

Comment: It's good logic.  The agony begins if you can't get each vehicles information.  Too bad there isn't a feed out there where you can suck all of those variables in....well...maybe there is.  I would imagine the data would have a subscription cost though.

Comment: I've seen a couple sites that have this kind of information on lots of cars.  something like a cars.com or Edmunds that contains data for used cars.  Might be harder to find for some newer / rare cars.  If you are looking for this on your own vehicle, you should be able to find your tire size and redline just by looking at the car.  gear ratios should in in a good service manual.  They might even be in the 'glove box' manual.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if they have a feed that could be consumed by an application to suck that kind of data in?  Screen scraping would be pure misery.

Comment: @rpmerf I understood the calculation. But the problem is I am calculating the gear from speed/rpm. I am using an OBD to get the speed and rpm values and hence speed/rpm is giving me which gear I am driving. The calculation that you stated has speed/rpm to find the correct gear. So, its kind of in a loop. Hence I can never compare and say whether I am shifting gears correctly

Comment: @DucatiKiller Hard to say.  Seems like something you wouldn't want to do without notifying them.  For legal reason.  Who knows, there might be a database online that contains all of this info accessible by web services.  I might be posting a million dollar idea...

Comment: @SoumyaSen Determining if someone is shifting correctly (at the correct RPM) is always difficult.  I would say there's 3 types of driving styles to consider - MPG, normal, power.  If there is a engine load variable you can grab, that would likely be best.  Use that with throttle position and RPM to determine when the user is bogging and needs to downshift or when the RPM is high enough that they can shift up.  Might take some AI to learn the characteristics of the vehicle.  There is also to consider when the vehicle is on an incline.  Load SHOULD take care of that.

Comment: throttle position and RPM might even be enough if you can see they are at something like 50% throttle at 1500 RPM and the RPM is hardly increasing.  Or if they are at 3000 RPM and like 5% throttle and basically maintaining RPM.  The challenge is determining thresholds.  You will want to compare engine acceleration with throttle position to determine a load on the engine.  I'm wondering how different cases will effect this - uphill, downhill, towing, powerful engine in a little car, weak engine in a big car.  This is why a bit of AI might be necessary to learn what is normal.